# Difficulty understanding 3rd dimension in MATLAB 'cat' command

Tags: matlab

I am reading matlab online documentation for fliplr command and there i came across a command 'cat'
It is used for concatenation. 
First argument of cat command specifies dimension along which concatenation will occur. example if first argument is 1 ,matrices are concatenated along columns and if first argument is 2, matrices will be concatenated along rows. But what if first argument is 3 as in this scenario.
I am confused how it is acting as shown in current scenario in attached photo. **What will be contents of A after assignment or execution of cat command? and  what is the meaning of highlighted lines? Does '3' means third dimension?If yes,how can be that possible?Will it be in form of pages with first matrix[1 2;3 4] on first page and second matrix [5 6;7 8] on second page 
(Please correct me if i am wrong)**

[cat command query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT8mI.png)

Comment: Yes, you get a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: Hi engr! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use screenshots to include textual data. Just copy and paste it into a code block in your question. Or if you must use a screenshot, drag and drop it onto your question so it's displayed inline, instead of as a link.

Comment: @AndrewJanke ok sir,got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's a 3-dimensional array. Matlab supports N-dimensional arrays. See the [Matlab documentation for Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html).

> What will be contents of A after assignment or execution of cat command?

A 3-dimensional array, with the inputs arranged in "pages" along the 3rd dimension.

> what is the meaning of highlighted lines?

The array is 3-dimensional, but your computer screen is only 2-dimensional, so Matlab has to come up with some other way of displaying 3-D arrays in 2 dimensions. Here, it breaks it into the 2-D slices that are along each index of the higher dimensions.

```
A(:,:,1) = 

  1    2
  3    4

A(:,:,2) =
```

The `:`s mean "all indexes along this dimension". The `1` in `(:,:,1)` means it's the first index along dimension 3. The `2` in `(:,:,2)` means it's the second index along dimension 3.

> Does '3' means third dimension?

Yes.

> If yes,how can be that possible?

You can fold however many dimensions you want into the single dimension of memory address by doing index transformations. It's an extension of how you can have a 2-D array in the first place, when they layout of computer memory is 1-dimensional. See the Matlab doco.

> Will it be in form of pages with first matrix[1 2;3 4] on first page and second matrix [5 6;7 8] on second page?

Yes.